# Unable to detect app launch from Widget extension in macos

Tags: widgetkit

When a widget is clicked in the notification center in mac, then the registered app is getting launched. According to the apple documentation,

> If you are not using widgetUrl or link control then containing app
> opens with application(_:continue:restorationHandler:) and userInfo
> has WidgetCenter.UserInfoKey.

However, in my case, the app is launched but the  [application(_:continue:restorationHandler:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsapplicationdelegate/1428471-application) is not getting invoked.I m not using widgetURL or link control in my swiftUI views. Is there something I m missing?

This my implementation of the method.

```
func application(_ application: NSApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: @escaping ([NSUserActivityRestoring]) -> Void) -> Bool {
                    
        //for widget launch
        guard let userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any] = userActivity.userInfo else {
            NSLog(AppDelegate.TAG + "Error in unwrapping userInfo optional!")
            return false
        }
        
        NSLog(AppDelegate.TAG + "userInfo = " + String(describing: userInfo))

        return true
    }
```